# Generic class with where constraint on base class, but only allowing derived classes

Tags: c#, generics, where-clause

I have a class `MediaCollection<T>` that represents a playlists of songs, videos or pictures. I also have three classes: `Song`, `Video` and `Picture` that all inherits from a `AMediaElement` abstract class. My `MediaCollection<T>` class has the following constraints:

```
class MediaCollection<T>
    where T : AMediaElement, new()
{
}
```

This allows me to have collections of songs, pictures, videos but also of just any `AMediaElement`!

How can I prevent the creation of objects of type `MediaCollection<AMediaElement>`? I could make the `MediaCollection` abstract and then make three other classes `SongCollection`, `PictureCollection` and `VideoCollection`, but I would prefer a solution using the `where` clause.

Comment: You can't. Just make you class abstract as you say. That is what abstract classes are for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well turns out it works. I tested it wrong by creating a `List<AMediaElement>` object instead of a `MediaCollection<AMediaElement>`.. Since my where clause specifies `new()`, I cannot use the abstract class `AMediaElement`, which is what I want.

I knew I hit that "Ask question" button too fast..